# Download files php always damaged

Tags: php, download

Im trying to make a script to download images from my localhost. Just for a schoolproject.

I get the filename via the url ("$_GET['file']"). Then i run this script. Every time the file is damaged and can't be viewed. I want to download images, but when i tried a word document it also was damaged. This is my code:

```
<?php
//get file
$file = $_GET['file'];
//set path of file
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/blackbox/mediafiles/"; 
$fullPath = $path.$file;
if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // fore a download
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
}
    header("Cache-control: private"); // open files directly
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
fclose ($fd);
exit;
?>
```

Anybody has and idea what goes wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

Try opening the file explicitly in binary mode:

```
if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "rb")) {
```

As the documentation on [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) states:

> Windows offers a text-mode translation flag ('t') which will
>   transparently translate \n to \r\n when working with the file. In
>   contrast, you can also use 'b' to force binary mode, which will not
>   translate your data. To use these flags, specify either 'b' or 't' as
>   the last character of the mode parameter.
>
> The default translation mode depends on the SAPI and version of PHP
>   that you are using, so you are encouraged to always specify the
>   appropriate flag for portability reasons. You should use the 't' mode
>   if you are working with plain-text files and you use \n to delimit
>   your line endings in your script, but expect your files to be readable
>   with applications such as notepad. You should use the 'b' in all other
>   cases.
>
> If you do not specify the 'b' flag when working with binary files, you
>   may experience strange problems with your data, including broken image
>   files and strange problems with \r\n characters.

Comment: I dont know how or what but from 0% success it went to 100% success. I tried binary mode and it also works:) Still thanks for ur answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) instead of manually reading file and outputting.

Also, please note, that $_GET['file'] can contain '../' and open any file, which is a security risk. Use the [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function (if all files are in the same directory) or restrict access to files outside the mediafiles directory

```
<?php
//get file
$file = $_GET['file'];
//set path of file
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/blackbox/mediafiles/"; 
$fullPath = $path. basename($file);
if (is_readable($fullPath) {
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // fore a download
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($fullPath));
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
    header("Cache-control: private"); // open files directly
    readfile($fullPath);
}
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either something is throwing an error from PHP, or you have leading whitespace before the opening tag in the file (`<?php`).

Do two things:

- Make sure the `<` of `<?php` is **the first** character in the file. Make sure your script doesn't have a byte order marker in it.
- Add these lines to the top of the script: `error_reporting(0); ini_set('display_errors', 0);`

Note that if disabling errors fixes your problem it means that **there is an error which needs to be fixed**, it is not a final solution to the problem!

Using [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is also shorter, safer and more efficient than opening a file pointer and looping it.

Comment: Thank you! After a very long search this was the solution (adding those two lines) for me!

Answer (score 1):

At first its not your answer. But you should really look at Security in PHP. On Your script you can access all files over the GET Parameter and DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Don't trust a user.

You should filter your variables at first or map them with a known list of files before deliver them to a user.

[PHPSec](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/)